# PHP file download issue - stop redirection if file does not exist while using GET method

Tags: php

I have main.php file, on which I have many "sub pages" (there are tabs and you can switch them so http://mydomain.com/main.php address does not change). I receive them dynamically via ajax requests. On one of such "sub page" I have download links. For example

```
                  <a href="dwnl.php?file=fish.avi">fish</a>
```

in dwnl.php file I have something like this

```
 // . . . . .
 $file =basename($_GET['file']);
 if(file_exists($file))
 {
   // download file
 }
 else  exit;
```

my problem occurs when file does not exist (i.e. in 'else' block of my dwnl.php file). If users click such link, browser redirects them to http://mydomain.com/dwnl.php?file=...  address. How can I forbid such redirection? I would like to do it using PHP (if it is possible). So, what should I do in 'else' block?

Comment: Your script seems to be vulnerable to download any arbitrary file (i.e. path traversal).

Comment: yes I know, this is just a toy example

Comment: why dont you should the download link only if `file_exists` ?

Comment: If file does not exist there is nothing to download. So, I just checking this condition.

Answer (score 0):

In else you can redirect to $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
This is redirect to your referer page.

Else if possible to check earlier
you can check file_exist and place href if file exists.

Comment: Thank you very much for your anwser Biswajit, but it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried 2nd option ?
"if possible to check earlier you can check file_exist and place href if file exists."

Also can you please post what error you are getting in the second method

Comment: I know, this is good option but I want to consider any kind of circumstances in my code.

Comment: I put the line $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in else block. But if file does not exists, browser still redierects me to 'dnwl.php?file=fish.avi' page.

Comment: I don't want to refresh my page, because as I mentioned in my question I have dynamic content which I get via ajax requests on my main.php file. So, if the page is being refreshed the content will be lost.

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']  this gives u the url from which it is called 
You have to put "header" to redirect to that location.

Comment: Thank you Biswajit, I know what you mean, but it refreshes my page, see my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, depending on the way your script is setup, is to use a header redirect.

```
<?php
header( "LOCATON: /not-found.php" );
die();
?>
```

This will redirect the user to whatever page you want.  As some other people have already said though, you should be very careful about dealing with file downloads in that way to prevent various exploits.  I would sanitize the filename before passing into any functions that grab file contents and also limit the possible download directories to only the locations you absolutely need to download from.  Don't trust open_basedir to protect you in any of the above situations, either.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but  I don't want to rederect user anywhere. I want to stay same 'main.php' page, even if file does not exist. I dont want to use header( "location:main.php"), because it refreshes the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

1) You may output a simple html with an error message and with a timeouted [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) tag.
Redirect to http://example.com/ after 5 seconds:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='http://example.com/'">
```

2) You may use [header()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to redirect immediatelly without any message:

```
header("Location: http://site.com/page?var=123");
```

3) You may set error **404** file not found:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found', true, 404);
```